# Multiple Upload Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to use bootstrap to upload multiple files from User. I can see that if i select more than one file it does indeed upload but I am looking for a way for the user to be able to hit the choose files button more than once to attach more files. Has anyone had any luck using this with bootstrap?

```
  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                        Attachment(s)
                        (Attach multiple files.)
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                            <input id="input-2" name="input2[]" type="file" class="file" multiple data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="true">
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is my [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/v3Lwxvhg/)

Comment: This doesn't qualify as a valid answer, but here's a link that might help you: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax.  It was the top google search result for me when I searched "ajax upload file".  Basically you're going to have to figure out how to leverage both AJAX and the [FormData Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).  As I said, this isn't a good fit for an answer on here.  Your question is too broad.  Try googling a few tutorials and when you get stuck feel free to post another question about that particular issue.

Comment: I'm not really sure what this has to do with Bootstrap - Bootstrap can't help you upload a _single_ file never mind multiple

Comment: and the [FileList Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList).  Kind of an important part to forget, sorry.  I think that part is where most of the cross browser support tanks.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This however seems more pertinent to how to send data back to the server. I am actually going to use knockout Js and send a byte[] back to the server that way. What i want to accomplish is that when they select an item they can click that button again before sending to server to attach another file. If i select more than one file they show up now. I want the user to be able to hit the button more than once.

Comment: Also, my fiddle has been updated. The browse button should be able to be hit more than once so they can select another file.

Comment: Cool fileupload, @LeonardoTrimarchi, but when I use the browe button again, the previouslyu selected files disappear.

Comment: @LeifNeland yup that was the issue i was having.

Comment: Oh, I thought "Also, my fiddle has been updated. " ment you had updated your fiddle with the solution. Sorry I misunderstood.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to upload a multiple files just put "multiple" inside the input file tag like this.

< input type="file" name="img" multiple>

```
<input id="input-2" name="input2[]" type="file" class="file"  data-show-upload="false" data-show-caption="true" multiple>
```